# Scale up the size of my of all points in scatter plot while still having the points anchored to a `size` variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to scale up the size of my of points in geom_jitter or geom_point and still have the points anchored to a `size` variable (in my case `n`)? Essentially I'd like to control all the points being smaller or larger.

I've tried increasing the values of the `n` variable by scaling that variable by 10 and 100, but this did not change the size of points.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, vs) %>% count() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = vs, size = n)) + 
    geom_jitter(height = .1, fill = "blue", colour = "white", pch = 21)
```

Comment: Maybe shift the `range` in `scale_size` up or down?

Comment: Beat me to it, I was about to suggest `scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 100))`

Comment: Or use `scale_size_area`; see [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_size.html) for examples of any of the above.

Comment: All of these solutions worked. Thank you.

Comment: I had no idea one could pipe into ggplot(). Crazy. Thanks for that!