# How to display the average of points that share x-values with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's the ggplot I have:

```
  listTimelinePlot <- ggplot(listDf, aes(x=N, y=Measurement_Value,color="List")) +
    xlab("n") +
    ylab("Time to append n items") +
    scale_x_log10() +
    scale_y_log10() +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

`N` is an array of integers that may contain duplicate values. As a result, in the resulting plot there are multiple points that share the same x-value:

[image]

How do I make it so that only one point is displayed per x-value, namely a point with its y-value equal to the average of the points' y-values? I'm assuming that the 'joints' created by `geom_line()` meet at the mean y-value.

Comment: The geom line connects all the points - it doesn't know what the mean is. It's probably connecting them in whatever order they are in your data frame.

Comment: ggplot is really good at plotting the data you give it. If you want it to plot means, give it means. Use the R-FAQ on [calculating means by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061) to get a nice summary data frame and plot that.

Comment: or , like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550156/, one can also summarise and pipe directly into ggplot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just compress your dataframe to means in the first place. `ddply` from the `plyr` package should do the job.

```
newListDF <- ddply(listDF, "N", numcolwise(mean))
```

The first input to the function is the data, the second is the column you want to categorise by, and the last column is the function you want to apply to the groupings (`numcolwise` is required to make the function apply in the correct direction of the data frame).

This will give you a data frame where we have calculate the mean of the N values for each x. Look at the names for this dataframe and you can use this as an input to ggplot instead.